# NoSuchMethodError on AmazonDynamoDB client Configuration

Tags: java, rest, jersey, amazon-dynamodb

All,

I am developing a series of REST services using JERSEY which talk to Amazon DynamoDB service using AWS SDK. The REST services are hosted in TOMCAT Server. However while executing the following code

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Test", "Test");       
AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Mar 08, 2015 6:28:25 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<init>(Lcom/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration;)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.adjustClientConfiguration(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:397)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:302)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:283)
```

This code seems to work in a normal java application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you executing the code? who's building the classpath? Is it Eclipse? Maven?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a different version of the lib is used at the runtime. Check out the version of JAR that contains **AmazonDynamoDBClient** and make sure that this class has the proper method. Then check out the version that is used at the runtime. It might be connected with Tomcat configuration. I faced with a similar issue related to JodaTime once I used it in WebLogic.